# Arguments to APPLY in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, apply, map-function

I am having the following trouble: when trying to use APPLY function with a MAPCAR call, the lambda function passed to APPLY, which contains only one parameter, the list returned by MAPCAR, gives the following error :
`*** - EVAL/APPLY: too many arguments given to :LAMBDA`

The following code identifies if a heterogenous list has the last atom at any level a numerical atom.

```lisp
(DEFUN hasLastNumeric (L)
  (COND
   ((NUMBERP L) T)
   ((ATOM L) NIL)
   ((LISTP L)
    (APPLY #'(LAMBDA (Lst)
                     (COND ((EQ (LAST Lst) T) T)
                           (T NIL)))
           (MAPCAR 'hasLastNumeric L)))))

(WRITE (hasLastNumeric '(1 2 5)))
```

Comment: Note that the language is called Common Lisp, shorter: CL. There is also an implementation of Common Lisp called CLISP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call a function eg. `(#'(lambda (a b) (+ a b)) 2 3)` there is a requirement that the number of arguments fits the number of provided arguments. When using `apply` the requirements are the same so `(apply #'(lambda (one) ...) lst)` require that `lst` is only one element list like `'(a)`, but it cannot be `'()` or `'(a b)`. The only way to support variable number of arguments you need to use `&rest` arguments eg. `(apply #'(lambda (&rest lst) ...) '(a b))`

Looking at the logic I don't understand it. You want to return `t` when you have encountered a list with the last element as a number but also searched list elements on the way and returned early had you found them. It should be possible without the use of `last` at each step. eg.

```
(defun has-a-last-numeric (lst)
  (labels ((helper (lst)
             (loop :for (e . rest) :on lst
                   :if (and (null rest) (numberp e))
                       :do (return-from has-a-last-numeric t)
                   :if (listp e)
                       :do (helper e))))
    (helper lst)))
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to use MAPCAR, as for homework. The &rest approach works.

Comment: @DariusCătinaș Note that if you `apply` with a lambda with `rest` it has the same effect as just binding the result in a `let` and do the code in the let instead, like Rainer points out. I don't think you catch the "any level" requirement with `mapcar` though.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need APPLY. Why would you use it? Remember: APPLY calls a function and uses the provided list as the list of arguments.

MAPCAR returns a list.

```
(let ((foo (mapcar #'1+ '(1 2 3 4))))
   (cond ((eql (last foo) ...) ...)
       ...))
```

Check also what `last` actually returns...